# SolrNet Newbie - How to handle multiple Where Clauses

Tags: sql-server, solr, solrnet, full-text-search

I just started exploring SolrNet. Previously I have been using MSSQL FULL TEXT.

In sql server, my query make full text searches and also have multiple joins and Where clauses. I am also using custom paging to return only the 10 rows out of millions.

I have read few solrNet docs and run sample apps provided on the blogs. All worked well so far. Just need to get an idea, What do I do with JOINS and WHERE clauses??

e.g. If user searches for Samsung, db would return 100k records, but if users searches for Samsung && City='New york' && Price >'500' then he would only get couple of thousands records.

- Do I add all columns in Solr and write WHERE clauses in Solr?
- What do I do about SQL JOINS?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no joins in Solr. From the [Solr wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaDesign):

> Solr provides one table. Storing a set
>   database tables in an index generally
>   requires denormalizing some of the
>   tables. Attempts to avoid
>   denormalizing usually fail.

About WHERE clauses (i.e. filtering), see [Querying in SolrNet](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/Querying), [Solr query syntax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax), and [Common Solr query parameters](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters).

Comment: Thanks for the tips Mauricio.

Comment: Just couple of questions, if you could guide mein with your experience of SolrNet. 1) How much would it slow down the full text search in Solr if I have almost 5 filters in the query. Secondly, I have got proximity search implemented in my MS SQL db which formulates the nearest location IDs by latitude and longitude. Wat's the best way to get this done with Solr. i.e. Should I just formulate the nearest location names before sending query to Solr. And then use something (equivalent to SQL IN operator) in Solr to match all of those location names as well?

Comment: @Peter: 1. depends on what those filters are, but typical filters aren't noticeable. 2. see http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch

Comment: Just need another performance tip if possible... I will be storing titles and descriptions of each document in the Solr. Description would normally be 256 chars long but it could go up to 1024 chars. I have got 2 to 4 millions of these rows and still want the blazing fast results. Will it be a performance issue or should I just store titles and not the descriptions? It would be more useful if I could search the descriptions to get more relevant results.

Comment: @Peter: if you need to search in the description, then index the description, with those numbers there won't be a significant perf hit.

Comment: @Mauricio Everything going good so far. The only problem is faced is with the case sensitivity of the Filters. e.g. new SolrQueryByField("City", "Chicago") returns the results but SolrQueryByField("City", "chicago") does not return any return because "chicago" is in lower case. I have searched the internet but couldn't get a clue how to turn case sensitivity off for filters. Any help plz? I dnt want any of my fields to be case sensitive, how can i achieve this?

Comment: @Peter: please post a new question about that.

Comment: Querying in SolrNet now moved to: https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Querying.md

Answer (score 1):

The Solr equivalent of your where clauses is to map your columns to fields and run queries based on the query syntax. A query like your example:

```
 Samsung && City='New york' && Price >'500'
```

could be translated to something like this in Solr:

```
 q=Samsung AND city:"new york" AND price:[500 TO *]
```

You need to take some care when you map your database to a Solr schema, specifically you will probably have to denormalize your data. See [this page on the Solr wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaDesign) for more information. Basically, you can't really do complex JOINs in Solr. It's a "flat" index.